# asp.net mvc dropdownlist no ViewData item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, viewdata

i start to study mvc, try to add dropdownlist, make construction

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("ddl") %>
```

but it show error

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'ddl'

why? i use simple code, only pass name parameter, so why the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable'"
```

It means that helper method is expecting an item of type `'IEnumerable'` for e.g, `List<>` with an Id `'ddl'`

If you are trying to display a DropDownList which has items from some static source, here is one way to do this.

```
          // create new IEnummerable 
          List<string> ddl = 
          new List<string>(new [] {"item1","item2" };   

          // add Items        
          ddl.Add("Item1");
          ddl.Add("Item2");

          // return View which holds ddl now
          ViewData["ddl "] = ddl ;
          return View();
```

---

For more insight have a look at

- [**Understanding HTML Helpers**](http://www.superexpert.com/blog/archive/2009/03/03/chapter-6-understanding-html-helpers.aspx)
- [**How to create a DropDownList with
  ASP.NET MVC**](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/10/how-to-create-a-dropdownlist-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Actually `Html.DropDownList` is an HTML helper that create html `select` element. When you pass `ddl` as argument it expects to get an array or list or something like that (an object implementing `IEnumerable` interface) to populate the dropdownlist. try it like this:

In Controller:

```
ViewData["ddl"]=new string[]{'Jan',  'Feb','Mar','Apr'.......'Dec'};
```

then it will create a select element containing the given values. For more information read [this article](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/10/how-to-create-a-dropdownlist-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867117/how-to-add-static-list-of-items-in-mvc-html-dropdownlist/867218#867218) is an example of adding a DropDownList in ASP.NET-MVC. You need to provide an item of type 'IEnumerable' with a key 'dll' in the ViewData, as the error says.