# C# MVC Dropdownlist no ViewData item

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having an issue with a dropdownlist I have in a `PartialView`.

Basically get the following error
`There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Status'.`

Here is my `ActionResult` method inside the controller

```
[HttpGet]
public  ActionResult Status()
{
   List<SelectListItem> Status = new List<SelectListItem>();

   Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Open", Value = "1" });
   Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Closed", Value = "2" });
   Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Delete", Value = "3" });

   ViewData["Status"] = Status;

   return View();
}
```

My `Status` Partial View where I call the select list

```
@Html.DropDownList("Status", ViewData["Status"] as SelectList)
```

And then I call the partial view from my main view as follows

```
@Html.Partial("Status")
```

I am just not sure why its giving the above error. I took at look at this [asp.net mvc dropdownlist no ViewData item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308731/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist-no-viewdata-item) and still not able to rectify the issue?

**Update**

As per @MikeDebela solution my Status Action Item was never been called. So used the following syntax to call the Action directly

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Status");}
```

Comment: Your code totally works fine when copied and pasted in a local MVC5 project

Comment: You pass a `List<SelectListItem>` into view data and try to cast it to `SelectList` that cast wont work

Comment: @Shyju, I don't think so. You can create a `SelectList` from a `List<SelectListItem>` but only if there is some TypeConverter I don't casting would work. Do you have some reference material I can look at to verify this?

Comment: @Nkosi. Check this fiddle which does that https://dotnetfiddle.net/KRxJhN

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look. thanks @Shyju.

Comment: Hi Shyju I am not sure why mine isn't working? However does it matter if I am using Partial views? Because as mentioned above I am calling a partial view inside my main view.

Comment: The reason is your `Status` action will never called. Use `@{Html.RenderAction("Status");}` instead

Comment: Thanks @MikeDebela for the solution. It works grand now :)

Comment: @MikeDebela you should add that as an answer so that the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Partial` helper, the runtime looks for the view and renders a string (your action will never get executed). On the other hand, `RenderAction` executes the action and displays the result. So, use:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Status");}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownList("Status", new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable) ViewData["Status"],"Text","Value"))
```

you can use this line to fill dropdownlist with ViewData

Comment: There is something wrong with your answer. `IEnumerable` requires 1 type arguments

Comment: try this @Html.DropDownList("Status", new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable) ViewData["Status"],"Text","Value"))

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim for the correction however it is now giving me a new error `Value cannot be null.`

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the code as follows because it is working with me

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> Status = new List<SelectListItem>();

        Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Open", Value = "1" });
        Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Closed", Value = "2" });
        Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Delete", Value = "3" });

        ViewData["Status"] = Status;
        return View();
    }


@Html.DropDownList("Status", new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Status"], "Value", "Text"))
```

or you can use

```
@Html.DropDownList("Status", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Status"])
```

Comment: Thanks again Ibrahim. However It is giving me the following error `System.InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Status'.`

Comment: you must use ViewData?

Comment: I am using `ViewData` Ibrahim

Comment: i know try with viewbag

Comment: Same error as with ViewData :( I feel it is something to with Partial Views.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125418/discussion-between-ibrahim-alsurkhi-and-kevin).