# I'm trying to convert a drop down to a html helper.dropdownfor()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My drop down code is currently below and I know what I need is in this format:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectlist
```

What I'm currently using is this code and I need to convert it to the ienumerable selectlistitem with the following information

```
<select id="paperStyle" name="paperStyleList">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Select Style</option>
        <option value="APA">APA</option>
        <option value="Chicago">Chicago</option>
        <option value="Harvard">Harvard</option>
        <option value="MLA">MLA</option>
        <option value="Oxford">Oxford</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This link might be userful 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867117/how-to-add-static-list-of-items-in-mvc-html-dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CustomerInfo()
        {

            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Chicago", Value = "Chicago", Selected = false });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "APA", Value = "APA", Selected = false });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Harvard", Value = "Harvard", Selected = false });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Oxford", Value = "Oxford", Selected = false });

            ViewBag.paperStyle= new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text");
            return View();
        }
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("CustomerId", (SelectList)ViewBag.paperStyle, "--Select--")
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.paperStyle, Model.paperStyleList.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Value = item, Text = item }), "Select Style")
```

or this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.paperStyle, new SelectList(Model.paperStyleList), "Select Style")
```

where `paperStyle` is a property of your model and `paperStyleList` is your list with values (APA,Chicago,etc) of type `IEnumerable` or `List` for that matter